# changing visual style for lua exe created with wsrlua.exe

Tags: lua, exe, iup

I am trying to create an Windows Gui exe with srlua (5.1)
it created successfully but with classic windows like visual styles. 
I wanted a xp or modern win8 style. The script as I run with Lua for Windows's wlua.exe
shows a modern win8 style. what do i do? Do I need to recompile srlua with win8 comctrl ver 6.0.0 style OR
WLUA.EXE Still can be used for exe building by replacing wsrlua with it.

Thanks.

Comment: i m on windows 8 with Lua for Windows 5.1.4 and srlua 5.1.

Comment: will this work, "copy wlua.exe+myscript.wlua my.exe"?

Comment: No, this will not work, because srlua.exe does a trick to load the lua code from the own executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resulting executable must have the manifest that enables visual styles. I don't use srlua, but I think you have to rebuild srlua.exe to be built just like wlua.exe is.

There are a few differences between lua.exe and wlua.exe:

- not a console application (-subsystem:windows)
- have a WinMain (see wmain.c in LuaBinaries source)
- includes a resource file with a manifest (see wlua.rc)

Comment: Thanks Sir for your elaborative answer.